# What is the limit of $(1-cos(5x))/(sin^2(4x))$ as x approaches 0?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Step by step solution would be very appreciated, I know I can use l'hopital rule but can someone explain it to me? Thanks!

Comment: You must show your efforts so that someone can help you

Comment: it is a stereo-type high school limit. In all these cases you should convert $(1-\cos{k x})$ into $2 \sin^2 \frac{kx}{2}$ then simplify it with the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$1-\cos(2u)
=2 \sin^2(u)
$,
$1-\cos(5x)
=2\sin^2(5x/2)
$.

Therefore
$\frac{1-\cos(5x)}{\sin^2(4x)}
=\frac{2\sin^2(5x/2)}{\sin^2(4x)}
$.

Now apply
$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}
= 1
$.